# Get all documents from an index of an elasticsearch cluster and index it in another elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, elasticsearch-bulk-api

My goal here is to get all documents from an index of an ES cluster and insert them in another ES cluster keeping the same metadata.

I had a look at mget API to retrieve data and Bulk API to insert it but this Bulk API needs a special structure:

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```

So my idea is to retrieve my data of EScluster1 in a file and rearranged it to meet the structure of Bulk API and index it to EScluster2.

Do you see a better and/or faster way to proceed?

Comment: Take a look at [snapshot/restore](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html) feature of ES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[elasticdump](https://www.npmjs.org/package/elasticdump) does this. If you want to do this manually, you'll want to query using [scroll](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) and then [bulk index](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) what comes out of that. Not too hard to script together. With elastic dump you can pump the data around without writing to a file. However, it is kind of limited when you have e.g. parent/child relations in your index.

Comment: Elasticdump now uses scan/scroll internally